# How to use give Date format using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have piece of code which is written like this but it is not showing any alert when i enter invalid format. Here is my piece of code,

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#From_Date label.control input', function (event) {
var txtfdate=document.querySelector('#From_Date label.control input ').value;

    if(txtfdate.match(/^(19|20)\d\d-(0\d|1[012])-(0\d|1\d|2\d|3[01])$/i)==null){
        alert("Enter From_Date in YYYY-MM-DD format only");
        return false;
    }else{
        alert("Correct..."+txtfdate);
    }
});
```

Need suggestion where am doing mistake.

I have my HTML code which is written in div like this

```
 <div id="From_Date" class="leaf">
 <label class="control input text" title="">
    <span class="wrap">From_Date</span>
     <input class="" type="text" value="[Null]"/>
    <span class="warning"></span>
 </label>
 </div>
```

Comment: are you having any JS errors on the console? It works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/hntjp/

Comment: No errors. Okay fine it is working in jsfiddle code which u have shared. But when i execute same in jasper server then it is not showing any error. how to resolve.

Comment: maybe is the version of JQuery? on JsFiddle i'm using 1.10

Answer (score 0):

use blur instead, and also your selector for txtfdate seems weird, you already specify the id then you can just get its value with `val()`

```
jQuery(document).on('blur', '#From_Date label.control input', function (event) {
var txtfdate=$('#From_Date label.control input').val();

if(txtfdate.match(/^(19|20)\d\d-(0\d|1[012])-(0\d|1\d|2\d|3[01])$/i)==null){
alert("Enter From_Date in YYYY-MM-DD format only");
return false;
}else{
alert("Correct..."+txtfdate);
}
});
```

jsfiddel
http://jsfiddle.net/VcqCL/

Comment: hi Shiang, please check my edited code of html where am picking data

Comment: ok updated it will work now, when you type the date and on blur (when you leave the text area) validate will show